# Fit bounding box to gnuplot legend

Tags: graphics, eps, gnuplot, bounding-box

**Summary**: Is there a way to automatically reduce the bounding box of an eps file to only fit displayed text?

**Details**:

A while ago I asked a [question about combining multiple gnuplot graphs into a single figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84889/combining-multiple-eps-files-into-a-single-figure).  I am trying to do something similar, but this time I also want to only have one legend for all the figures.  To accomplish this I want to generate a graph with only the legend, and then place that in the appropriate place in the figure as a subfigure.

I am able to generate a gnuplot with only the legend by turning off everything else and setting the plot range to a section that does not display any data using these commands:

```
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset title
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
set xrange[-50:-10]
set yrange[-50:-10]
```

This gives me a graph with only the key set.  The problem is that the bounding box still contains the space for the actual graph (shown below).  What I would like to do is crop this to something that only contains the key so that I can combine that easily with the other plots (as described in the answer to my other question).

I am able to get something closer to what I want by manually editing the bounding box, but I would prefer a fully scripted solution if possible.  I've tried a few things but haven't gotten it working yet so I thought I would ask here since my earlier question received a very helpful answer.

**Initial eps file**:
  [image]

**Desired eps file (after editing bounding box):**
[image]

Comment: An untested idea: convert EPS to PDF, use the `pdfcrop` tool, convert it back from PDF to EPS. Or try GhostScript and use the `bbox` device?

Comment: @Malipivo thanks `pdfcrop` does what I need.

Comment: @Malipivo care to answer?

Comment: @Paul Gessler Please, go ahead, if you can. I'd love to answer, but I cannot do it these days. The OP's question is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151646/is-there-a-way-to-remove-white-margins-when-importing-a-pdf-file/151669#151669

Answer (score 0):

One trick to deal with circumstances in which gnuplot creates an incorrect bounding box is to output to postscript (not encapsulated) and then make a system call to ps2eps to generate a corrected file. An example, using `set size ratio` to create the bad box:

```
set term postscript color
set size ratio 2
set output "wrong_bb.ps"
plot x**2
!ps2eps --ignoreBB -rotate=+ -f wrong_bb.ps
```

You may need to play around with the rotate option: `+` means 90 degrees clockwise, `-` means 90 degrees anticlockwise and `^` means 180 degrees.