# fit full page multiple subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want to arrange 33 subfigures by putting them in groups of 3, I tried the following solution:

```
\documentclass[smallextended,table]{svjour3} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
%start first row
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG/IMG_RQs/cli/....pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG/IMG_RQs/cli/....pdf}
\end{subfigure}

\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG/IMG_RQs/cli/....pdf}
 %end first row
....
%start last row...
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG/IMG_RQs/cli/....pdf}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG/IMG_RQs/cli/....pdf}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG/IMG_RQs/cli/....pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is partially correct, indeed, the figures occupy three columns, however, the last group of images is drawn outside the vertical margin of the document,
as shown in figure [image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, can you provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Note that `graphicx` provides a set of dummy images such as `example-image`, `example-image-a`, `example-image-b` etc. you could use with `\includegraphics`. This helps to provide a self-contained MWE.

Comment: Similars: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211546/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425560/1952

Comment: Do you want to `fit` all images into the same page or accept that they spread along different pages?

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot fit 33 images on one page, one simple solution would be to use `longtable` instead of `figure`. The `adjustbox` is added to set image dimensions in one place. Similarly, the macro `\N` is created to add the same vertical space after each row. A similar effect can be accomplished by changing `arraystretch` to a value larger than `1.0`

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{F}   % F>1.0 causes vertical stretch
```

but then change `\N` to the regular `\\`.

`showframe` is not important in the final version. It serves as a reference by drawing frames around all pages.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{showframe}   % For a reference in drafts
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}

\adjustboxset{width=0.28\linewidth}
\newcommand\N{\\[10pt]}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
    \caption{Set of N x 3 figures} \\
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \includegraphics{example-image-c} \N
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `longtable` proposed by `Celdor`, you can use a `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, blanker]
\foreach \i in {1,...,11}
    {\tcbincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-c}}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]